# Edge for Mac: certificate is "revoked" instead of "self-signed" warning

Tags: macos, ssl-certificate, microsoft-edge

One of the local devices has self-signed certificate which Edge for Mac is showing as revoked (NET::ERR_CERT_REVOKED), and I'm unable to override it, however the same Edge on Windows 10 shows less severe error (NET::ERR_CERT_AUTHORITY_INVALID) and let's me through.  I don't control the device, so is there a way to make Mac version let me through?

Running "Edge Version 79.0.309.71 (Official build) (64-bit)" on Mac.

Answer (score 1):

Does the certificate work on other browsers on Mac? If possible and no privacy issues involved, you could include the link to problem website so that we can visit the site to inspect the site certificate.

Besides, you could also refer to [this article](https://www.ssl.com/guide/troubleshooting-ssl-tls-browser-errors-and-warnings/) about troubleshooting certificate issues. In the last part **Revoked Certificate**, it says:

> Solution: generate a new website certificate chained to a valid, publicly-trusted root and intermediate certificates.

You could also try the solution in [this article](https://css-tricks.com/getting-around-revoked-certificate-osx/) about solving the revoked certificate issue in OSX. The article uses Safari as an example. If you want to view certificates using Edge, you could go to url `edge://settings/?search=certificates` then click **Manage certificates**:

[image]

Comment: It's an ESXi on local network which I don't control and it's unlikely to get fixed.  And yes, Safari warns about *self-signed* certificate and allows me to continue, so it seems to be a problem with the Edge.  Opening the certificates list does indeed show that the host certificate was added as "trusted".